# How Do I Keep the User Logged in with Google Sign In?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

I am trying to keep the user logged in after they quit the app. When the user presses the home button and then comes back again it does keep them logged in (and it loads the data from the Google Classroom API I am using). But, when the user force closes the app it will not. I would like to have the user stay logged in after they force close the app (just like when they press the home button). Is there a way to do this? I am using Google Signin & Firebase for logging in.

Here I log in the user:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // ...
    if let error = error {
        // ...
        return
    }

    print("User Signed into Google")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

    // Set the OAuth authorizer for the Classroom API
    service.authorizer = authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    // ...
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
        print("User is Signed into Firebase using Google Sign In")

        //let welcomeScreen = WelcomeScreenViewController()

        //welcomeScreen.performSegueToHomeworkScreen()
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            for controller in navigationController.viewControllers {
                if let LoginViewController = controller as? LogInViewContoller {
                    LoginViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInToHome", sender: nil)
                    break
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And when the user opens the app :

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The current Firebase user remains logged in even after force quitting the app. Since the code is calling `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()`, that would sign a user into their Google account, but it would not sign them into Firebase automatically. Instead of using this, add a [state change listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  if user == nil {
    // prompt user to sign in
  } else {
    // you know the current user
  }
}
```

This function closure will be run every time a change is made to authentication, so if a user then signs out, this will be triggered again and you will see that there is no longer a user signed in and can handle it accordingly. When a user signs in, the closure is again run and you can do what you need to do with the user.

Comment: On the account screen, it does still display the username and email. So I guess the user is still logged in then... But then when I am trying to retrieve data from Google Classroom it doesn't display anything.